# autorefresh a div automatically

Tags: php, html

Hi, I have a chat in php and I want to make the div on the right automatically update every 5 seconds automatically without reloading the whole page, because when I open the chat in two different windows with two different accounts and send a message I have to press f5 every time, is there a way to update that div only? i tried with an auto reload but the whole page refreshes.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: PHP does not run code in the browser, so once the initial HTML is sent, you need to use JavaScript. In this specific case, you need JavaScript which makes a request to the server for fresh data and updates the page as you wish; that process is called "AJAX". Have a look for some tutorials with those keywords.

Comment: Ajax is definitely the solution, but if you want to discover other possibility, you can try to use Socket.io here their get started page : https://socket.io/get-started/chat

Comment: If you just want to get information from the server in an interval, you can also try server sent events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events. Use SSE in combination with an async request to push new postings to the server.